# JavaScript, how to get the pdf page from listening to window.print by onbeforeprint

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get the pdf page that window.print create, I don't want to use converters. Can I get the page by listening to onbeforeprint?

```js
window.onbeforeprint = function(event) {
window.open(event)
};
window.print();
```

I want know which element in the event will give me the pdf page

Comment: so, if I using onafterprint action, can I  catch the PDF gape?, is it that simple?

Comment: but, whatever I want it's not to know when it finish or when it begin, I jast want the pdf page insted of to create it by myself, i want to catch this page, that it possible?

Comment: got it, so what do you say? what the best way to ceate pdf page from my html? when I need to use whis textarea.

Comment: ok, and what the way to do this? are you recommend of iframe? or something else?

Comment: but it's not related to the user' I need to create pdf page from my html and save it in my DB, do you know tell me what the best way for this?

Comment: ok, thenks alot